# How can I change the style font thought agGridReact component in my reactjs app?

Tags: reactjs, font-family, ag-grid-react

The `<AgGridReact>` has a default `fontfamily: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Segoe UI,Roboto,Oxygen-Sans,Ubuntu,Cantarell,Helvetica Neue,sans-serif`.

That font comes from the style .ag-theme-balham . I am not able to change it into my react-app.

I have the index.css default in my app and I put on the style:

```
.ag-theme-balham{
  font-family: Times New Roman, Times, serif;
}
```

enter code here

but this way did not work. Does someone have any idea?

Comment: The !important rule overrides that particular property.
`.ag-theme-balham{ 
  font-family: Times New Roman, Times, serif !important;
}`

Comment: Thank you. I did it and worked fine.